# How to replace all column names (node ID) with node coordinates?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an x table as shown below.
[image]
In x table, I want to replace column names (node ID) with node coordinates. So that column names can be represented as node coordinates.
The following two tables show node coordinates.
[image]
[image]
I would appreciate a lot if any advices.

Comment: You are expected to show tables as text and in the question itself because we cannot copy any data from images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can first combine x-coordinate and y-coordinate so that they actually look like a coordinate. For e.g.:
`x-coordinate=138.22` and `y-coordinate=1549.64` can be converted to `138.22,1549.64`
You can simply do that using `aggregate` function
Given a dataframe like this:

```
>>cord_df
  location of sensors  X-coordinate  Y-coordinate
0                  n1        88.123        100.25
1                  n3        33.254        325.45
2                  n4        78.200         19.93
```

You can do the following:

```
>>cord_df['coordinate'] = cord_df[['X-coordinate', 'Y-coordinate']].astype(str).agg(','.join, axis=1)
>>cord_df
  location of sensors  X-coordinate  Y-coordinate     coordinate
0                  n1        88.123        100.25  88.123,100.25
1                  n3        33.254        325.45  33.254,325.45
2                  n4        78.200         19.93     78.2,19.93
```

Now you can use the location of sensors and coordinate columns to rename the columns in your actual dataframe.
Given a dataframe like this:

```
>>df
     n1     n3     n4
0  22.0  50.25  20.00
1  23.5  48.30  25.12
2  27.3  13.35  33.30
```

You can get this:

```
>>df = df.rename(columns=cord_df[['location of sensors', 'coordinate']].set_index('location of sensors')['coordinate'])
>>df
   88.123,100.25  33.254,325.45  78.2,19.93
0           22.0          50.25       20.00
1           23.5          48.30       25.12
2           27.3          13.35       33.30
```

Now you can access the columns by the coordinate values:

```
df['78.2,19.93']
0    20.00
1    25.12
2    33.30
Name: 78.2,19.93, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question?  I want to train an SVM based on this new dataframe and a y series showing the results, but finally I received an error that can not convert string to float: "361.51, 1100.77" that is column name represented as the form of coordinate. Could you please give me some ideas?